# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=100}^{\infty} a_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I just had this problem on a final and I was confused about proving the reverse direction. For example, what if $a_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$?

Then $\sum_{n=100}^{\infty} a_n$ would converge, but the first term in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$  would be undefined.

I think I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, $a_n$ is a real sequence, so it is a map from the natural numbers to the real numbers. But then, $a_1$ does not map to the real numbers at all, so $a_n$ isn't even a real sequence, simply because $a_1$ is flouting the norms.

Comment: You are probably expected to assume that $a_n$ is defined for all $n\ge1$.  Was there maybe an introduction to the question saying something like "for all $n\ge1$, let $a_n$ be a real number"?

Comment: It seems in this theorem one must assume $a_n$ is defined for all $n \ge 1,$ otherwise the left sum is not defined.

Comment: I suppose $a_n$ is defined for all natural number $n$.

Comment: @David It was not specified that $a_n$ must be defined for all $n \geq 1$ or anything along those lines... I just chose to pretend that was given when doing the proof and hoped for the best with my test score.

Comment: General principle about examination questions: assume whatever is needed for the question to make sense.  It's also a good idea to state those assumptions.

Comment: Do you need help with the proof itself, or has this discussion about assumptions made on $a_n$ cleared everything up for you?

Comment: @infinitylord I'm ok with the proof itself, thank you.

Comment: If $a_n$ was not properly defined then it was a poorly stated exam question.  You have my sympathy.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ and for $n \ge 100$ let $s_n=\sum_{k=100}^na_k$. Furthermore let$a:=a_1+...+a_{99}$.

If $n \ge 100$ we then have

$S_n=a+s_n$.

We get:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent $ \iff (S_n)$ is convergent $ \iff (s_n)$ is convergent $ \iff \sum_{n=100}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy criterion:

$S_m = \sum_{i=100}^{m} a_k$  convergent .

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

There is a $m \ge n \ge n_0 \gt 100$ such that

$|S_m-S_n| \lt \epsilon.$

Use this $n_0$ to establish that

$R_m= \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i$ is Cauchy,

hence convergent.